# Rich Text Editor with extra or external plugins support

Tags: text-editor, plug-in, angular

I am looking for a free rich text editor which supports extra or external plugins like **MathType** and **Chemtype**. I tried with CKEditor5 via its official documentation in Angular 13, but it gives some build errors, and conflicts after executing the program installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Syncfusion Angular RichTextEditor

https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion